# Вывод значения переменной из функции

Tags: c++

```
void sravn(int n) {
 int a;
 if (n > 5) {
     a = 5;
 }
 else {
    a = 4;
 }
}

int main() {
int n, rez, a;
cin >> n;
sravn(n);
cout << a;
return 0;
}
```

Хочу, чтобы выводилось значение переменной a. Если введенное число больше 5 - вывести 5, иначе 4. Понимаю, что a - это локальная переменная. Но всё же, как подправить код, я хочу именно таким алгоритмом, а не другим, не надо предлагать другое решение задачи.

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно это?

```
int sravn(int n) {
    return (n > 5) ? 5 : 4;
}

int main() {
    int n, rez, a;
    cin >> n;
    cout << sravn(n);
}
```

Или это?

```
void sravn(int n) {
    cout << ((n > 5) ? 5 : 4);
}

int main() {
    int n, rez, a;
    cin >> n;
    sravn(n);
}
```

Или вот это?

```
void sravn(int n, int& a) {
    a = (n > 5) ? 5 : 4;
}

int main() {
    int n, rez, a;
    cin >> n;
    sravn(n,a);
    cout << a;
}
```

Comment: Мне нужно третье. А что означает вопрос и амперсанд в void? 
Вызывая sravn(n,a), мы как бы делаем переменную a глобальной?

Comment: @letsgo1239, вместо знака вопроса должна быть запятая. Амперсанд объявляет ссылку.

Comment: @letsgo1239, нет, переменная `a` глобальной не делается, а передается по ссылке.

Comment: Очепятка, простите. Запятая, конечно. И передача переменной по ссылке.

Comment: думаю первый вариант, но  cout << (a = sravn(n));